# The Radon-Nikodym derivative for a sequence of dependent variables

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Suppose that a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ is given. Let $W=\{W_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0}$ be a sequence of $\mathbb{P}$-i.i.d real-valued random variables on $\Omega$. Furthermore, assume that $\mathbb{Q}$ be a new probablity measure on $\Sigma$, and $W$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-i.i.d and that $\mathbb{Q}_{W_1} \sim \mathbb{P}_{W_1}$. We denote by $\mathcal{F}^{W} = \{\mathcal{F}_n^W\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ the natural filtration of $W$. Then, one can say that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$ and for all $D\in \mathcal{F}_n^W = \sigma(W_1, W_2, .., W_n)$
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{Q}(D) = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\Big[I_D \prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{d\mathbb{Q}_{W_1}}{d\mathbb{P}_{W_1}}(W_j)\Big]
\end{equation}
or equivalently,
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\Big|_{\mathcal{F}_n^W} = \prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{d\mathbb{Q}_{W_1}}{d\mathbb{P}_{W_1}}(W_j)
\end{equation}
Now, my question is what if $W_j's$ is not independent. In this case, how does the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\Big|_{\mathcal{F}_n^W}$ look like?

Comment: what means $\mathbb{Q}_{W_1} \sim \mathbb{P}_{W_1}$ exactly?

Comment: The notations $\mathbb{Q}_{W_1}$ and $\mathbb{P}_{W_1}$ stand for the distribution of $W_1$ under measure $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}$, respectively. The notation $\sim$ denotes the equivalency between two measures. We say that  $\mathbb{Q}_{W_1}$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{P}_{W_1}$ (in the sense of absolute continuity).

Comment: if the $W_j$ are not independent then the product of "densities" (Radon-Nikodym derivatives) is not the "density" (R-N derivative) of the joint distribution, so the expression must be written as a product of "conditional distributions" (kernel measures) instead. You can take a look about it form in the book of Robert Ash of probability and measure, page 109

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will have a look.

Comment: sorry, the book of Ash cover a different, but related, topic. To write the distribution of non independent distributions as a product you must use recursively the theorem of [disintegration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem) of measures. In short: you need to define, recursively, the conditional distributions of the $W_j$ and multiply them all together. Also take a look [here](http://www.stat.yale.edu/~jtc5/papers/ConditioningAsDisintegration.pdf)

Comment: Ok, I will check all. Actually, my question is subjected to the paper "A characterization of equivalent martingale measures in a renewal risk model with applications to premium calculation principles". In lemma 2.2, authors assumed $W_j$ are independent. I wanted to express the lemma in a more general setting where $W_j$ are dependent. I hope that the paper you sent me can answer my question. Thanks again.

Comment: @Masacroso, I had a quick look at the paper that takes about disintegration, and I realized that regular conditional probability is known as an example of it.  Roughly speaking, one can say that
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\Big|_{\mathcal{F}_n^W} = \prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{d\mathbb{Q}_{W_j|\mathbf{W}_{j-1}}}{d\mathbb{P}_{W_j|\mathbf{W}_{j-1}}}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{W}_{j-1}=(W_1, W_2, ..., W_{j-1})$.

Comment: I wonder if we can equivalently write the following relation for the Radon-Nikodym derivative:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\Big|_{\mathcal{F}_n^W} = \prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{d\mathbb{Q}_{W_j|T_{j-1}}}{d\mathbb{P}_{W_j|T_{j-1}}}
\end{equation}
where $T_n= \sum_{i=1}^{n}W_i$. My reason is that $\sigma (W_1, W_2, ..., W_n) = \sigma (T_1, T_2, ..., T_n)$.